# How to restricted to access AWS API Gateway endpoint by Cognito user id

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I am trying to implement an e-commerce application backend by using AWS Cognito, Api-Gateway, and Lambda.

To create a new Item, users must be logged in. Once created the item, the Logged used will be the creator of the item. I already created an Item-create endpoint and added the Cognito-JWT authorizer for the Apigateway endpoint.

Now I need to implement Item-update endpoint. The relevant Item update must be allowed only for the creator of the Item. API maybe like this.

```
/items/{item-id} PUT
body : { title, price... }
header { Authorization: Cognito-JWT-Token }
```

What is the best way to implement this kind of feature using the AWS ecosystem.  Or any best practices to implement this kind of feature.

Answer (score 0):

You would create a property `owner` for each item that is a user ID. Normally you'd use the `sub` claim from the token which is a unique ID. However, for various reasons, I wouldn't recommend using the subject value with cognito. You can use email just ensure safeguards are in place if someone deletes their account and a new one is created with the same email.

Whatever you choose, in your handler compare the owner with the validated token claim. Allow if they match, disallow if they don't.

Comment: Thank you @Andrew. That's means we have to handle that inside the lambda handler.

Comment: For REST API yes. If you are using identity pool you can enforce fine-grained access in [dynamodb](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_dynamodb_items.html) and [S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_cognito-bucket.html). But I wouldn't adopt that approach as the migration paths from it are pretty awful.